# Relation between a distribution in $\mathbb{R}^{1}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Tags: distribution-theory

From Chapter 1, Exercise 8 and 9, Strichartz's book: Distribution theory & fourier transforms

8. Suppose $f$ is a distribution on $\mathbb{R}^1$. Show that $<F,\phi> =      <f,\phi_y>$, for $\phi \in \mathcal{D} (\mathbb{R}^2)$. where$\phi_y(x) = \phi(x,y)$ (here y is any fixed value), defines a distribution on $\mathbb{R}^2$.
9. Suppose f is a distribution on $\mathbb{R}^1$. Show that 
   $<G,\phi> = \int_{-\infty}^\infty<f,\phi_y>dy$ for $\phi\in\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ defines a distribution on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is $G$ the same as as $F$ in problem 8.

In problem 8 isn't the functional on $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^1)$ dependent on the value $y$. So how does it give a the same value for all such test functions $\phi\in\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ irrespective of the value of $y$.

Problem 9 does recognize that the value is dependent upon $y$ therefore, the variable of the integrand is $y$. This is confusing to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is correct: in problem 8, $F$ depends on $y$, so it should better be called $F_y$, or similar. But, since $y$ is assumed *fixed*, the author dropped it. In problem 9 $y$ is not fixed anylonger, so the index makes sense now: $G=\int \limits _{-\infty} ^\infty <F_y, \phi> \Bbb d y$. (In particular, this shows that $F$ and $G$ are not the same, because $F$ is a distribution in dimension $2$, while $G$ is in dimension $1$; but maybe you are asked whether $G$ and $f$ are the same?)

Comment: Prob 8:Since a distribution maps a test function to a number, therefore $\phi(x,y) \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is mapped to a number irrespective of the value $y$. However, R.H.S. is dependent upon $y$ since $f$ is a distribution upon $\phi_y(x) \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^1)$.

Comment: Prob 9: I checked with the text of the problem. It ends with "Is $G$ the same as $F$ in problem 8?"

Comment: I'm still waiting for clarification

Comment: @Ricky: Both your comments above are answered in my post. Have you read it?

Comment: $F_y$ doesn't make sense to me. $F$ is a distribution on $\phi \in \mathcal{D(\mathbb{R}^2)}$. Hence to each $\phi$ corresponds to a single number not dependent upon y which the rhs suggests

Comment: Using "dummy variables" in a visual but non-rigorous writing, what the authors do is to define a distribution $F_y$ of $(x,z)$ by $\int F_y (x,z) \phi (x,z) \Bbb d x \Bbb d z = \int f(x) \phi (x,y) \Bbb d x$. Not rigorous (because $f$ and $F_y$ might not always be functions), but very clear I hope.

Comment: I get it. For problem 9 $G$ can be interpreted as a distribution in $\mathcal{D(\mathbb{R}^2)}$ given the functional defined for each fixed value of y. Although it is not obvious why it is equal to $F$

Comment: Again, in "dummy variables", $G(x,y)$ is defined by $\iint G(x,y) \phi (x,y) \Bbb d x \Bbb d y = \int \Big( \int f(x) \phi (x,y) \Bbb d x  \Big) \Bbb d y$. Formally (i.e. carelessly) interchanging the order of integration gets us $\int f(x) \Big( \int \phi (x,y) \Bbb d y \Big) \Bbb d x$. This shows that the action of $G$ on $\phi$ is totally different from the action of $F_y$ on $\phi$, so $G \ne F_y$. (Using $F$ instead of $F_y$ is a minor yet regrettable glitch on the part of the authors.)